# How to install nginx 1.14.X inside docker?

Tags: docker, nginx

```
# 1. use ubuntu 16.04 as base image
FROM ubuntu:16.04

# defining user root
USER root

# OS update
RUN apt-get update

# Installing PHP and NginX
RUN apt-get install -y nginx=1.4.* php7.0

# Remove the default Nginx configuration file
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Copy a configuration file from the current directory
ADD nginx.conf /etc/nginx/

ADD web /usr/share/nginx/html/

# Append "daemon off;" to the beginning of the configuration
RUN echo "daemon off;" >> /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 90

# Set the default command to execute
# when creating a new container
CMD service nginx start
```

This is my Dockerfile. I want to Install 1.14.2 of Nginx but Error occurs:

```
E: Version '1.4.*' for 'nginx' was not found.
```

How can I install specific version of nginx inside docker this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @larsks `Ubuntu 16.04` supports nginx only till version `1.10.3`

[Official wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/NGINX) with more detail

So best/safe option would be either move your base OS to `18.04` or use nginx `1.10.3`

Just for reference how you can install Nginx from src.

```
wget https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.14.0.tar.gz
tar zxf nginx-1.14.0.tar.gz
cd nginx-1.14.0
make
sudo make install
sudo nginx
```

More detail [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/#sources_download)

Answer (score 1):

You've based your Docker image on `ubuntu:16.04`.  The 16.04 release of Ubuntu does not include nginx 1.14.x; it only has nginx 1.10.3:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu:16.04 bash
root@1d780d71ebd5:/# apt update
[...]
root@1d780d71ebd5:/# apt show nginx
Package: nginx
Version: 1.10.3-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
[...]
```

If you want a more recent version of nginx, consider basing your image on a more recent Ubuntu release, or building it yourself from source.  For example, the 18.04 release of Ubuntu includes nginx 1.14:

```
$ docker run -it --rm ubuntu:18.04 bash
root@d7ca6d8960f6:/# apt update
[...]
root@d7ca6d8960f6:/# apt show nginx
Package: nginx
Version: 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you.
Is there anyway I can install 1.14.X in ubuntu 16.04 ?
How to build it from source with docker ?

Answer (score 0):

Other options for this is you can download tar(source code) and extract it.
Below are the command which you need to follow:-

```
$ wget https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.14.0.tar.gz
$ tar zxf nginx-1.14.0.tar.gz
$ cd nginx-1.14.0
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo nginx
```

More Details can be seen here [Nginx- Install doc](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/)

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM ubuntu

ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.14.0-0ubuntu1.2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install nginx=$NGINX_VERSION
```

Comment: Your answer would benefit from specifying why it's necessary to specify a different version. You also made a good start by replacing two different `RUN` lines with one - why not complete your work by providing the top half of a working `Dockerfile` with all three `RUN` statements combined?

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer the [official images](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx?tab=tags&page=1&name=1.14) and only self-build an image if there is no alternative. This saves you work, is more flexible and makes maintaining (updates) easier.  In your case, just use the 1.14 tag:

```
FROM nginx:1.14
```

However, from today it would make sense to use a more recent release insead. But the process is the same, just look in the Docker hub for avaliable tags (e.g. 1.23) and replace it in your Dockerfile.

PHP also have [official images](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) if needed. They can be used for different stacks, e.g. Apache2 with `mod_php`, PHP-FPM for use with Nginx (should be hosted in a seperate container) or just the PHP CLI.

It's also possible to further simplify your Dockerfile. For example, the step

```
RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

is not required. The `COPY` overrides the existing one. It's also not really clean to copy an entire `nginx.conf` from your host and then modifying it. I'd either modify the existing one or copy my own. But in the second case, it should be a complete file. Otherwise it's confusing when someone looks at the Nginx configuration file and doesn't now that further modifications are done in the Dockerfile.